# Upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013 broke something

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, upgrade

*I try to use PDFCreator in a Asp.Net MVC context.
I wrote a Console Application project to do the creating part and this works well.
The problem comes with the calling part from MVC because the exe seem to launch a dialog or something like that and the error **"unable to show dialog in this context"** appears.
Is there a simple solution or is it impossible to solve and i need to change everything?
EDIT: I use PDFCreator for his ability to convert files into pdf and combining them into one.*

**EDIT : It seem to be a wider problem, linked with the one i asked earlier in a deleted question... 
So here is the renew question:**

Upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013 have broken something in my solution because i've got some weird behaviors that i dont have on a new one.
Someone knows something about this issue?

Comment: Please add your code you tried

Comment: If you can't get it work using PDFCreator, I can recommend [RazorPDF](http://nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF)

Comment: As added, i need the ability to convert and combine documents, so if you have failed using PDFCreator, it seems that i need to change the entire solution...

Comment: @Murali the code i use is the basic code for a console application, the problem is throw by the call to PDFCreator `_PDFCreator = new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator();`